# Doctrine2: How to recycle an entity object for multiple inserts

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using symfony 2 as framework, I want to insert about 100k row at a time, it took about 12 minutes to insert to the database, but creating 100k object of the entity is huge, and for my case, it's useless because only one attribute that changes from an entity to another, so recycling the object is a good start to optimise the process.
How can I recycle an entity object and re-persist it.
Thank's

Comment: Take a look at this doctrine doc page : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

Comment: That's what I'doing actually

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to solve similar problem short time ago and after lot of optimization steps I ended up with "out of framework PHP script" for inserting huge batch of data rows directly through PDO. Working with objects and some data abstraction layer as Doctrine is great practice for clear and sustainable code, but unfortunately (and obviously) it brings lot of overhead and inefectivity in perspective of processing.
So, I would recommend this option, based on my experience, to you too.